# deleted records above this and matching primary key in txt file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to delete some matching records while doing txt processing

```
list.txt
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,8,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,8,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
```

Code:

```
awk -v add='tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6' '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; split(add, arr, ",") }
($1==arr[1] && $2==arr[2] && $3==arr[3] && $4=="status0") { append=$5 FS $6 }
END{ print add, (append?append:"NULL,NULL") }' list.txt
```

This will give output: tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6,0,1

Once I got output I need to delete matching records with 'tag1,slate1,flag1' before this record 'tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1'[From this record only we got '0,1' values to output]

and then need to add output record to list.txt at end

```
list.txt
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1 -> deleted records above this and matching [tag1,slate1,flag1], 
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6,0,1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2-pass approach, first to identify the line that matches your target values, then to print all appropriate lines:

```
awk -v add='tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6' '
    BEGIN {
        FS=OFS=","
        split(add,arr)
    }
    NR==FNR {
        if ( ($1==arr[1]) && ($2==arr[2]) && ($3==arr[3]) && ($4=="status0") ) {
            append = $5 OFS $6
            matchFnr = FNR
        }
        next
    }
    !( (FNR < matchFnr) && ($1==arr[1]) && ($2==arr[2]) && ($3==arr[3]) )
    END {
        print add OFS (append ? append : "NULL,NULL")
    }
' list.txt list.txt
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6,0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU sed** stream editor utility we will generate the sed code from the data to manipulate the data itself.

```
< list.txt sed -ne '/^tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,/=' |
sed -Ee '$!d
  s/.*/1,&!ba\n&!{/;a\
/^tag1,slate1,flag1,/d;b\
}\
h;:a\
p;$!d;g;s/0,/1,5,6,/
' |
sed -f - list.txt
```

- First step we get the last line's number that matches ** tag1,slate1,flag1,status0**
- Then based arround this number we write the sed code that will do our task
- To see what code came out of the second sed invocation comment the last sed invocation.

**Output:**

```
tag2,slate2,flag2,status0,2,3
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status0,0,1
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,2,3
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,status1,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,3,4
tag1,slate1,flag1,status1,5,6,0,1
```